# Duda con dataframe en Python (función apply)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo una duda que no he podido resolver, tengo el siguiente dataframe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer para aplicar la siguiente función en el dataframe y devolverlo en dos columnas nuevas:

```
def aplicar_funcion(valor1, valor2):
    suma = valor1+ valor2
    variacion = valor2/valor1-1
    return suma ,variacion
```

Lo que no sé es como llamar la función desde un dataframe, ya he usado la función `.apply` con un dataframe en otras ocasiones pero pasando y retornando solamente un argumento, pero para este caso no sé como usarlo.

Así lo estoy probando pero no funciona:

```
df['suma'], df['var'] = df[df['precio1',precio2]].apply(aplicar_funcion)
```

Específicamente este no es el ejercicio que necesito, lo que necesito es algo más complejo, lo puse como ejemplo para ver si alguien sabe como usar la función `.apply` con más de dos argumentos en un dataframe.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debería ser algo así:

```
df[['suma', 'variacion']]=df.apply(lambda x: suma_variacion(x['precio1'], x['precio2']),axis=1,result_type='expand')

def suma_variacion(valor1, valor2):
    suma = valor1+ valor2
    variacion = valor2/valor1-1
    return suma, variacion
```

Aquí la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646384/add-2-new-columns-to-existing-dataframe-using-apply):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646384/add-2-new-columns-to-existing-dataframe-using-apply

Comment: Me funcionó, gracias!

Comment: de nada, puedes seleccionar la respuesta como aceptada para que este la constancia de ello ,gracias :)